# Problem importing Tensorflow with Python 3.6.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 and Python 3.6.7 on Windows 10, however while importing Tensorflow, there is an error occurring, all the detailed descriptions and messages are appended below:
    I've tried to change my Python 3.7 which a lot of people said it is not compatible with Tensorflow to 3.6.7, but I still cannnot import Tensorflow, does anyone know what should I do to fix this problem? 
//=======================================================================

(tensorflow) C:\Users\user>python --version
    Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\user>python
Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 28 2018, 19:44:12) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows with the same python version. Try these steps:

1. Uninstall your existing TensorFlow from the conda enviroment
2. Install TensorFlow version 1.10.0 with conda package manager.

   `conda install tensorflow=1.10.0`
3. After the installation is completed, make sure you have 3 packages in the packages list : tensorflow , tensorflow-base and tensorboard.
4. The tensorflow-base package would solve the problem.
5. At last install the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1. conda create --name tensorflow python=3.6
2. activate tensorflow
3. conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.0.0
4. Try importing tensorflow
5. deactivate